# Restarting an FCI calculation in PySCF

Tags: python, pyscf, full-configuration-interaction

My question is, if there is a way to continue an earlier FCI calculation in PySCF.

Imagine you initially just need energies converged up to a certain threshold:

```
  cisolver = pyscf.fci.FCI(an_scf_object)
  cisolver.conv_tol = 1e-5
  e, fcivec = cisolver.kernel(verbose=5)
```

and later you decide that you need very accurate energies and CI vectors:

```
  cisolver = pyscf.fci.FCI(an_scf_object)
  cisolver.conv_tol = 1e-9
  e, fcivec = cisolver.kernel(verbose=5)
```

What properties could you write down after the initial run in order to restart from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do, is save the CI vector of your calculation and then use it as  starting point in a subsequent calculation, like so:

```
e, c = cisolver.kernel(verbose=5,ci0=c0)
```

where c0 is a numpy array containing the solution of another run.
I tested this for carbon in a STO-3G basis. First ran to a convergence of `1e-5`, saved the vector, then converged with saved vector to `1e-9`. This I compared to a run from scratch which was converged to `1e-9`. The continuation took 4.15s to converge while the calculation from scratch took 5.21s.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but it occurred to me while doing calculations, that this requires the calculation to complete, in order to save the `c0` vector. If a calculation crashes before completion, could a saved copy of the `c0` vector from previous FCI iterations be recovered for restarting the calculations? @Jannis have you only restarted from fully converged energies?

Comment: It looks like it can't be done unless a fully converged energy is obtained, but I've asked my question in more detail now [**here**](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10444/5). If either of you have insight about it this I would be so delighted to see an answer!

Comment: Also, this procedure failed for me on a larger basis set, see [**here**](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10453/5). @Jannis did you notice anything like this with your FCI or CISD calculations?

Answer (score 2):

## Preliminaries

The hint [by Sverus Snape](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9779/5) to use a numpy array was helpful, **but how does one do that?**

I found the answer at [How to save and load numpy.array() data properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55058828/1271772) and since there's also so many different options given there (e.g. `np.fromfile`, `np.loadtxt`, `np.load`, etc.) I would like to provide people with the solution that worked for me, and a minimum working example.

## Benchmark calculation (without restarting)

A calculation of the CISD energies for the lowest three electronic states of Ne in cc-pV5Z using this input with `conv_tol=1e-9` required 9 Davidson iterations to converge the ground state energy to this precision, and more than 30 Davidson iterations to converge the third highest of these electronic states:

```
davidson 34 5  |r|= 6.05e-05  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457311]  max|de|= -2.83e-09  lindep= 0.913
davidson 35 6  |r|= 3.02e-05  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457311]  max|de|= -1e-09  lindep= 0.738
root 2 converged  |r|= 2.1e-05  e= 0.8045731078550442  max|de|= -1.36e-10
converged 36 7  |r|= 2.1e-05  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457311]  max|de|= -1.36e-10
RCISD converged
RCISD root 0  E = -128.8839677954546
RCISD root 1  E = -127.7421970392584
RCISD root 2  E = -127.7421970216469
```

## Partial calculation (saves CI vector for later)

The example below does the same calculation but wtih `conv_tol=1e-5` and it saves the numpy array of the CI vector.  I ended up using the answer with the ***second*** highest net score on the above StackOverflow thread, because it was more straightforward, and because binary `.npy` files are more practically sized than ASCII `.txt` files (a solution with `.h5` would be even better, and for the PySCF coupled cluster code, they [do document](https://pyscf.org/user/cc.html#saving-and-restarting) such a solution).
The command that I used for saving the CI vector is in the last line below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import pyscf
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, fci,ci

mol = pyscf.M(atom = 'Ne 0 0 0',basis = 'cc-pv5z',verbose=5,output='out_1e-5_direct.txt')
mhf = scf.RHF(mol).run()
mci = ci.CISD(mhf).set(conv_tol=1e-5,nroots=3)
e, civec = mci.kernel()
np.save('civec.npy', civec)
```

Because of the lower convergence criterion, the ground state energy converged after only 5 Davidson iterations, and the highest of the three states sought had its energy converge at around the 19th Davidson iteration (all three energies are also ***slightly*** higher than in the previous calculation):

```
davidson 17 6  |r|= 0.00551  e= [-0.33719763  0.80457337  0.80459828]  max|de|= -1.57e-05  lindep= 0.691
davidson 18 7  |r|= 0.00339  e= [-0.33719763  0.80457337  0.80459439]  max|de|= -3.89e-06  lindep= 0.443
root 2 converged  |r|= 0.00128  e= 0.8045935429617836  max|de|= -8.5e-07
converged 19 8  |r|= 0.00132  e= [-0.33719763  0.80457337  0.80459354]  max|de|= -8.5e-07
RCISD converged
RCISD root 0  E = -128.8839677596848
RCISD root 1  E = -127.7421967633118
RCISD root 2  E = -127.7421765865402
```

My directory then had the following checkpoint file (not human-readible, since it's a binary file):

```
-rw-r----- 1 nike nike 4448072 Jan  4 17:42 civec.npy
```

## Calculation that reuses the saved CI vector

Now I'll recover the "benchmark" energies (`conv_tol=1e-9`) using the `.npy` file that was saved in the last line of the script in the previous section; it is reused in the last line of the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Author: Nike Dattani, nike@hpqc.org

import numpy as np
import pyscf
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, fci,ci

mol = pyscf.M(atom = 'Ne 0 0 0',basis = 'cc-pv5z',verbose=5,output='out_1e-9_restarted.txt')
mhf = scf.RHF(mol).run()
mci = ci.CISD(mhf).set(conv_tol=1e-9,nroots=3)
e, civec = mci.kernel(ci0=np.load('civec.npy'))
```

This gives roughly the same energies from the "benchmark" calculation, but with only about 2 Davidson iterations for the ground state energy, and about 12 iterations for the third energy sought:

```
davidson 0 3  |r|= 0.00132  e= [-0.33719763  0.80457337  0.80459354]  max|de|= 0.805  lindep= 0.816
davidson 1 6  |r|= 0.000962  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457312  0.80459334]  max|de|= -2.48e-07  lindep= 0.506
root 0 converged  |r|= 2.04e-05  e= -0.33719766591648676  max|de|= -8.9e-10
davidson 2 9  |r|= 0.000859  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80459321]  max|de|= -1.32e-07  lindep= 0.63
davidson 3 11  |r|= 0.00165  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80459283]  max|de|= -3.75e-07  lindep= 0.796
root 1 converged  |r|= 5.81e-06  e= 0.8045730910409581  max|de|= -6.13e-11
davidson 4 13  |r|= 0.00418  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80458896]  max|de|= -3.88e-06  lindep= 0.939
davidson 5 14  |r|= 0.00519  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457749]  max|de|= -1.15e-05  lindep= 0.892
davidson 6 15  |r|= 0.00117  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457335]  max|de|= -4.14e-06  lindep= 0.914
davidson 7 16  |r|= 0.00041  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457318]  max|de|= -1.66e-07  lindep= 0.775
davidson 8 3  |r|= 0.00041  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457318]  max|de|= 9.11e-11  lindep= 0.999
davidson 9 4  |r|= 0.000371  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457314]  max|de|= -3.54e-08  lindep= 0.692
davidson 10 5  |r|= 0.000219  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.8045731 ]  max|de|= -4.39e-08  lindep= 0.929
davidson 11 6  |r|= 7.38e-05  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457309]  max|de|= -7.99e-09  lindep= 0.781
root 2 converged  |r|= 3.04e-05  e= 0.8045730916435243  max|de|= -7.2e-10
converged 12 7  |r|= 3.04e-05  e= [-0.33719767  0.80457309  0.80457309]  max|de|= -7.2e-10
RCISD converged
RCISD root 0  E = -128.8839677954263
RCISD root 1  E = -127.7421970385624
RCISD root 2  E = -127.7421970378585
```

## Extra remarks

It's remarkable that when following the "save and restart" method, the ***total*** number of Davidson iterations is actually smaller than what was required when setting `conv_tol=1e-9` directly in one calculation.

This procedure might also be useful for finding higher excited state energies if your `nroots` parameter was set undesirably low during your first calculation.

## Availability of above input and output files

The input and output files for all three calculations in this answer are provided [here](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/9743/cisd). The files are described below:

| Calculation | Input file | Output file |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Benchmark calculation (`conv_tol=1-e9`) with no restart | `inp_1e-9_direct.py` | `out_1e-9_direct.py` |
| Partial calculation (`conv_tol=1-e5`), saves the checkpoint file | `inp_1e-5_direct.py` | `out_1e-5_direct.py` |
| Benchmark recovery (`conv_tol=1-e9`), using checkpoint file | `inp_1e-9_restarted.py` | `out_1e-9_restarted.py` |